# Minimal API: Dependency injection error - Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi, minimal-apis

I could not find answer that would resolve my issue. I'm getting 2 exceptions in my minimal API:

1: System.AggregateException

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MinApiEFCore.Data.ConnectRepo
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> MinApiEFCore.Data.ConnectRepo': Unable to resolve service for type
> 'DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.ServiceConnection' while attempting to
> activate 'MinApiEFCore.Data.ConnectRepo'.) (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MinApiEFCore.Data.IConnectRepo
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: MinApiEFCore.Data.ConnectRepo':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.ServiceConnection' while attempting to
> activate 'MinApiEFCore.Data.ConnectRepo'.)'

2: InvalidOperationException

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.ServiceConnection' while attempting to
> activate 'MinApiEFCore.Data.ConnectRepo'.

"ServiceConnection" is from an "external" class from DocuWare (via NuGet) used for creating a connection.

My IConnectRepo interface looks like this:

```
public interface IConnectRepo
{
    ServiceConnection CreateServiceConnectionAsync(Uri uri, string user, string password);        
}
```

ConnectRepo class:

```
public class ConnectRepo : IConnectRepo
{
    private ServiceConnection _serviceConnection;

    public ConnectRepo(ServiceConnection serviceConnection)
    {
        _serviceConnection = serviceConnection;
    }

    public ServiceConnection CreateServiceConnectionAsync(Uri uri, string user, string password)
    {
        //Organizations == null means I am not connected
        if (_serviceConnection.Organizations.FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            _serviceConnection = ServiceConnection.Create(uri, user, password);
        }
        return _serviceConnection;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
..
builder.Services.AddScoped<IConnectRepo, ConnectRepo>();
..
```

Still not sure why I cannot inject ServiceConnection in the constructor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've got to learn to understand what the error message is telling you - then you'll be able to solve these yourself. It's saying it can't create a ConnectRepo because it doesn't know what to give it to satisfy the dependency on ServiceConnection. So you must register a ServiceConnection with your DI container so that it has something to satisfy ConnectRepo's dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject `ServiceConnection` as it has not been added to DI container. You can register the service like following...

```
..
builder.Services.AddScoped<IConnectRepo, ConnectRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceConnection>();
..
```

...but then you will run into another problem as `ServiceConnection` doesn't have public parameterless constructor.

Resolution for this is to instruct DI container how to create ServiceConnection instance.

```
..
builder.Services.AddScoped<IConnectRepo, ConnectRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceConnection>(sp => ServiceConnection.Create("some service URI"));
..
```

Be aware that you might need to use different service lifetime to avoid performance issues.

[ServiceConnection documentation](https://developer.docuware.com/dotNet_API_Reference/PlatformServerClient/DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient.ServiceConnection.html)

[IServiceCollection extension methods documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Hi @dropoutcoder, thank you very much for your insight. I have been able to resolve the issue thanks to your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy you could resolved it.